# Querying 65k+ records with whereIn

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have an export functionality and I want to query and export using given ids. I found a solution of querying using `skip()` and `take()` but when now `whereIn('id', $ids)` giving me the error as it has 85k records as of now.

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1390 Prepared statement contains too many placeholders

The solution I was using was:

```
public function handle() {
    $max = 5000;
    $total = $this->givenIds->count();

    $pages = ceil($total / $max);

    for ($i = 1; $i < ($pages + 1); $i++) {
        $offset = (($i - 1) * $max);
        $start = ($offset == 0 ? 0 : ($offset + 1));

        MyModel::whereIn('id', $givenIds)
                 ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                 ->skip($start)
                 ->take($max)
                 ->get();

       // $this->generateTempCsv();
    }

    // $this->combineTempCSVs()
}
```

This was working fine without bottlenecking - until the too many placeholder error. Now that I received this error, I tried:

```
$query = MyModel::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')

foreach ($this->givenIds->chunk(2000) as $i => $chunk) {
    if ($i == 0) {
       $query = $query->whereIn('id', $chunk);
    } else {
       $query = $query->orWhereIn('id', $chunk);
    }
}
```

This gives the same error.

If I want to query using givenIds, and still want to keep "orderBy - created_at" without bottlenecking what should I do?

The givenIds come from Controller (as above code is Job):

```
$givenIds = MyModel::select('id', 'created_at')
                    ->where(function($q) use ($dateRange, $queries) {
                            $this->applyQueryFilters($q, $queries, $dateRange);
                     })
                     ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                     ->pluck('id');

Exporter::dispatch($givenIds)->onQueue('export');
```

PS: The reason I use `$givenIds` is because there are filters and first I get related ids after applying the filters and then passing the `$givenIds` into the job. Do I need to sort by id when getting `$givenIds` and depending the order from there?

Comment: how you obtain the  array content ?? if you build the array by a select you don't need  the IN clause

Comment: I added an edit which shows the Controller responsible for it

Comment: I'm not in lavavel so i can suggest just a solution based  on pure sql if you need

Comment: You should obviously use a JOIN

Comment: @scaisEdge Thanks but I'd like to know the Laravel's query builder way instead. - @ YourCommonSense how would you do it with Larave query builder?

Comment: You can use join with the query builder :) which version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @party-ring Laravel 5.8. Alberto's answer worked but I don't know what it does or if it has any side-effects. I'd be happy to know the Laravel approach too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: in your database config file, under `sql` or the driver you are using to connect to your database, add a field `options` like this

```
'options'=> [PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true]
```

PHP API infact says ([check this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php)):

> Some drivers do not support native prepared statements or have limited support for them.

Another solution should be to change the driver, but i suppose that adding a line to the database.php is easier to do

**Possible side effect reported:** this may cast the return values to string, which will effect your code if you are using `===` as comparison operator. You can solve this using the `protected $casts` variable in the models (if you are using Laravel)

Comment: Wow - this worked. What does this do exactly? Does it have any side-effect?

Comment: Glad too see it works... what exactly it does, i don't know, but PHP API doesn't says anything about side effects, i'll add the link to the API in the answer

Comment: Yes I did a quick reading there too - _PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES -  Enables or disables emulation of prepared statements_

Comment: yes exactly, i mean that i don't know what "emulation" means in that quote. However, mark as close the question if this solves your problem

Comment: **I found the side effect of this**. It casts all the values to string, e.g int `35` to `"35"` and boolean `true` to `"true"`

Comment: and in which case this produce any problem? Also the answer is giving you a second chance, changing the driver

Comment: Everything throughout the app is messed up even `Auth::user()->id == $model->id` because `350 == "350" = false`. Changing the driver? :D mysql is powerful enough

Comment: what? no, "350" == 350 is true, "350" === 350 is false... check this https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: Sorry you are correct. Another way to fix this issue with Laravel is using `protected $casts` in model. Anyhow, I wanted to give you a shoutout about its side-effect

Comment: Nice. What I think is what is it actually doing so that it can accept above 65k limit when it changes them to string. If you figure out some time in the future, please keep me posted

Comment: probably is because you can concatenate string, where instead integer and boolean no